# UIButton setHidden not working now?

Tags: xcode, ios6, uibutton

I have 10 or so buttons setup inside a method as follows:

```
@implementation MyViewController
UIButton *originalButton;

etc...

- (void)setupButtons
{
    originalButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [originalButton addTarget:self action:@selector(originalButtonWasPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    originalButton.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 30.0, 100.0, 39.0);
    UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"originalreg.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];
    UIImage *buttonImageHighlight = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"originalregblue.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];
    [originalButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [originalButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.view addSubview:originalButton];

    etc…
}
```

I decided to pull the common code into another method for efficiencies:

```
- (void)setupButton:(UIButton *)myButton withSelector:(SEL)selector withX:(CGFloat)x withY:(CGFloat)y withRegImage:(NSString *)regImage withHighlightImage:(NSString *)highlightImage
{
    myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 100.0, 39.0);
    UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:regImage] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];
    UIImage *buttonImageHighlight = [[UIImage imageNamed:highlightImage] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
}
```

…and call it as such:

```
- (void)setupButtons
{
    [self setupButton:originalButton withSelector:@selector(originalButtonWasPressed:) withX:20.0 withY:30.0 withRegImage:@"originalreg.png" withHighlightImage:@"originalregblue.png"];

    etc...
}
```

**THIS ALL WORKS** except, one of my buttons is used to hide all the others. In the original setup, pressing the "Hide Buttons" button resulted in the other buttons being hidden. Now, they remain on the screen. Here's the code for that:

```
[self setupButton:hideButtonsButton withSelector:@selector(hideButtonsButtonWasPressed:) withX:20.0 withY:530.0 withRegImage:@"hidebuttonsreg.png" withHighlightImage:@"hidebuttonsregblue.png"];

- (void)hideButtonsButtonWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    // hide the buttons
    originalButton.hidden = YES;
    originalButton.enabled = NO;

    etc…
}
```

I've confirmed this method is being called and the `setHidden/setEnabled` calls are being executed.

Any pointers gratefully received!
Tony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because your method uses single instance all the time. look at the first line of your initialization

```
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

replace this line with

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

it will return new instance of button each time.

YOu have Declared button instance like following ,right.

```
IBOutlet UIButton *btn1, *btn2, *btn3;
```

Now create a new button with your method as you have done before, just assign that button to respected button object

```
btn1 = [self setupButton:originalButton withSelector:@selector(originalButtonWasPressed:) withX:20.0 withY:30.0 withRegImage:@"originalreg.png" withHighlightImage:@"originalregblue.png"];

btn2 = [self setupButton:originalButton withSelector:@selector(duplicateButtonWasPressed:) withX:20.0 withY:30.0 withRegImage:@"duplicatereg.png" withHighlightImage:@"originalregblue.png"];

btn3 = [self setupButton:originalButton withSelector:@selector(olderButtonWasPressed:) withX:20.0 withY:30.0 withRegImage:@"olderreg.png" withHighlightImage:@"originalregblue.png"];
```

Comment: I'm confused at that since I declare all the UIButtons at the top (so they're available to all my methods). I thought passing these to `setupButton:withSelector...` would result in separate instances for each one? If I do as you say I won't be able to use the button instance in the other methods in this class?

Comment: my dear friend then you need to pass the object of that button in your customised method to get instance of declared button.                   your declared method does what i explained. it only returns single instance. but you can assign that instance to any button you declared.

Comment: i have show you whats the problem with your code, though you are marking it with Thumb Down. i m trying to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Dipen. Actually I have declared button instances such as `UIButton *originalButton, etc...` (programmatically not as IBOutlets if that matters) and I'm passing that as param to `setupButton:originalButton...`. So given your example, would it make sense to do: `originalButton = [self setupButton:originalButton withSelector...`?

Comment: thats what i am trying to explain dont pass button object in method. instead create new button instance each time using your method and return it. and assign that object to your respective button.

Comment: your argument is valid and very much welcome, but thats the part creating problem in your code.

Comment: sorry about thumbs-down. Not intentional. Must have responded to screen touch accidentally :)

Comment: I guess I'm still confused - thanks for your patience. When I declare `UIButton *originalButton;` and `UIButton *nextButton;` am I not creating instances of UIButton class? Thus if I do: `[self setupButton:originalButton …];` and `[self setupButton:nextButton…];` am I not passing two distinct instances to my method that can both exist with their own data/properties? In any case, I have it working now. I'm no longer passing the button as a parameter, but instead call the method like this: `originalButton = [self setupButton:@selector(…` which I think is where you were going. Thanks again Dipen.